# Is there a Subversion user's guide to Git?

Tags: svn, git

I am a new user in Git world. I used to use Subversion (using TortoiseSVN) and it is pretty easy. I would like to try Git but i got confused by the terms. Is there any documentation/guides that can explain me how to use Git?

For example, in Subversion I use checkout; in Git which commands should I use? Any good book about Git that I could use?

Comment: The [Git Community Book](http://book.git-scm.com/) available for free.

Comment: +1 for getting more than 30 votes and "beeing not constructive".

Comment: "Version Control by Example": http://www.ericsink.com/vcbe/ (free digital editions available)

Comment: For a more general introduction to DVCS in general check out http://hginit.com/. Its focused around Mercurial but the concepts are very similar. This article is actually the one that got me started with git in the end.

Comment: One can only find so many "closed as not constructive" with more than 30 votes before one think that it is StackOverflow policy that needs to change, and not the users fond of it...

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Here are two good guides:

- [Git - SVN Crash Course](http://git.or.cz/course/svn.html)
- [(Easy) Git for SVN users](http://www.gnome.org/~newren/eg/git-for-svn-users.html)

Comment: I would add Pro Git's Chapter 8, located at http://progit.org/book/ch8-1.html

Comment: The first one seems outdated, and [this](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/GitSvnCrashCourse) might be a better link now.

Comment: Updated link to the first one is: https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/GitSvnCrashCourse

Answer (score 7):

Best one I've come across is here:

[Git for Subversion Users](http://pointbeing.net/weblog/2009/09/git-for-subversion-users.html).

Answer (score 4):

Also [An introduction to `git-svn` for Subversion/SVK users and deserters](http://utsl.gen.nz/talks/git-svn/intro.html).

Answer (score 3):

Here is nice tutorial [Git for Windows developers](http://lostechies.com/jasonmeridth/2009/06/01/git-for-windows-developers-git-series-part-1/)

Answer (score 3):

i really enjoyed [gitimmersion.com](http://gitimmersion.com/)