# Where are good Git tutorials for SVN(Subversion) User?

Tags: git, svn, version-control

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a Subversion user's guide to Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1042280/is-there-a-subversion-users-guide-to-git)

Git is a version control system that is gaining popularity. I have been used it for a few months and I love it. Unfortunately, I find it difficult to introduce git to my co-workers in that they already get used to SubVersion.

I found the following tutorial helpful for me:

- [Git Magic](http://www-cs-students.stanford.edu/~blynn/gitmagic/)
- [Pro Git](http://progit.org/book/)
- Official Git Tutorial

However, none of the above items are written for Subversion users. Given that Subversion is also a popular VCS, I am wondering whether there exist some "tutorials" for helping people migrate from Subversion to Git?

Comment: Quite similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1042280/a-subversion-users-guide-to-git. An updated version would be http://people.gnome.org/~newren/eg/git-for-svn-users.html

Comment: Hackr has a good collection of GIT tutorials. Some of them assume no knowledge of SVN - http://hackr.io/tutorials/git

Answer (score 1):

You can find [here](http://git.or.cz/course/svn.html) A crash course for git, that shows comparison between SVN & GIT.
Was pretty useful to me when I made the transition.

Answer (score 1):

I would just go through the regular git tutorials like the links you listed (which are all good.)

You can look at something like this for a quick comparison:
http://divby0.blogspot.com/2010/11/git-vs-svn-basic-commandline-syntax.html

The main thing I explain is that with SVN, it's like a bank account with everyone making deposits and withdrawals from one central location (the repository). With git it's like you have your own bank strapped to your back, and it syncs with other people's banks.

Answer (score 0):

When I migrated, I found that the conversion tutorials didn't really cut it for me to be honest - I recommend you actually get hold of a book like "Version Control with Git" and read through it. You'll come away with a much deeper understanding of Git than if you just try and rush into it.

Answer (score 0):

Although written for Mercurial, Joel Spolsky's [Subversion Re-education](http://hginit.com/00.html) is a great resource highlighting the differences between subversion and git/mercurial.

The reason that "Git for SVN users" tutorials are rare is because they are two completely different beasts.  You really don't want to rely on cheatsheets (for example "git clone is like svn checkout") because you will never fully understand git if you continue to think of it in terms of subversion.  Although it is sometimes the easiest way to get someone from one VCS to another, it will do a disservice to them in the long run